Duplicate Job (or Apex or Flow) - before Merging records, Archive original records as Historical Data
We have a Screen Flow that can allow User to enter a duplicate PersonAccount record. Our User is non-technical and we do not want to prevent the User from creating a duplicate record by mistake.
Can I create a Duplicate Job that:
A. Returns true on a Matching Rule (which identifies Records A and B the same)
B. Sets off Apex or a Trigger that grabs data from Records A and B and saves them in a BeforeMergeArchive__c record?
C. Then, merges A and B
If not with standard Duplicate Management, how can we do this with Apex or Flow?

You could call FindDuplicates methods in Apex to find possible duplicates. In your flow, first collect the user input, then call an InvocableMethod that finds any duplicates, and if duplicates are found, then inserts the records (bypassing the Duplicate Rules warnings), save any changes you want to your custom object, and finally call Database.merge to merge the records.
